# How to make a preview of DIV in another DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, slide

I am making an application or a site in html/css/javascript that will allow me to create slides, add some text, image maybe change color and styles to every slide and than launch it as a whole presentation.

So far I have managed to make a really easy layout :

http://sandbox.padsbanger.pl/ss/

My question is:

How can I make a dynamic preview of a div on sidebar and a full view of slide on the right ? This would allow me to switch between the diffrent slides and make changes to them.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: For this project I am not allowed to use PHP.

EDIT 2:

I am not bothering about storing the data about slides somewhere in db. The idea of this app it to make a presentation consistig of a few slides and then launch it full screen view as a presentation.

Comment: Typically questions on SO are specific to a single concise programming problem.  Yours seems overly broad, covering several vague areas at once.  Additionally, people seeking help are expected to have done some prior research and/or have something to show for it.

Comment: I've seen far worse questions answered here. And i'm personnally interested in answers to this one :) Where should it be asked then?

Comment: @darma, I never said it was off-topic.  I'm saying that it needs some work.  The OP just asks "how can I create this really complex app" without posting any code for anything he's already attempted.  Does he expect you to write this code for him?  See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I have already googled for this problem but found nothing

Comment: Like Sparky672 said. This is a bit vague. My suggestion would be to use a PHP script that gets your information from a database. And then use Ajax to load it. A simpler method would be to hardcode the information into each div. And then set them to display none and use Jquery toggle them.

Comment: @Sparky672 : ok i see your point and i don't disagree :)

Comment: So sorry, but i forgot to mention, that I am not allowed to use PHP for this project.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck : i'm guessing the problem asked here is more related to front-end programming (zooming out on a block of HTML/CSS content and generate some kind of snapshot of it) than back-end / storage.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly is being asked here.  He's not allowed to use PHP yet he does not mention if he's allowed to use any server-side code at all.  ->  **Vague**

Comment: Yes, I am not bothering about storing the data about slides somewhere in db. The idea of this app it to make a presentation consistig of a few slides and then launch it full screen view as a presentation.

Comment: So what's the real purpose of all this then?  A CMS ?  If so, then you can't do that without a server side language.  Where do the slides come from?  Are they uploaded?  Again, you need a server-side language.

Comment: This whole thing is only getting more vague as you edit the OP and make comments.  Please read this:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: slides are pure html filled with DOM objects like <p> <ul> etc. They shoud be added via buttons like "add paragraph" so then DOM element on slide is created for this.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
.slajd * {
  zoom: 0.25;    
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);    
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;    
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);    
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;    
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);    
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

That would shrink all the content in the left 'preview' panes to 1/4 size. Then, when you click one just copy the innerHTML to the right pane and since it won't have the zoom/scale styles it will be full size.

As for the connecting - this will make all slides clickable. I suggest you add this to a `document.ready` block somewhere in the `HEAD`.

```
$('#leftcolumn').on('click', '.slajd', function() { 
    $('#rightcolumn').html($(this).html()); 
});
```

Comment: Just be sure to wrap all text in `SPAN` tags, otherwise it won't scale (at least in Chrome)

Comment: OK, you got me some direction, but how to connect the small preview slide with a big one ?

Comment: left and top properties stays lite that.. i dont see any impact on left and top properties of a div. though the size of my div has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the exact contents of the left sidebar in the main content area you can read the contents of the current sidebar using $this then use .html to read the content.

Take a look at Google Docs, slide/presentation as an example.

They basically size everything tiny in the left box which is just what's in the right.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save all of the design parameters in a data structure, for example:

```
var design =
[
    {
        type : "background-image",
        params :
        {
            url: "/images/snow.png"
        }
    },
    {
        type : "image",
        params :
        {
            x : 100,
            y : 300,
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            url: "/images/tree.png"
        }
    },
    {
        type : "text",
        params :
        {
            x : 100,
            y : 300,
            text : "Happy XMAS!",
            font :
            {
                size : 20
                family: arial;
            }
        }
    },
];
```

Here you have a background image, some text and a regular image.
The size parameters will be used normally on the regular sized slide but you will have to divide those parameters by the size ratio of the large slide & the small one for example:
if the large slide is 400x400 and the small one is 100x100 do this:

```
largeWidth  = 400;
largeHeight = 400;
smallWidth  = 100;
smallHeight = 100;
xRatio = Math.round( largeWidth / smallWidth );
yRatio = Math.round( largeHeight / smallHeight );
```

Now, when you draw the thumbnail slide you need to divide the coordinates of the large one (which are specified in the data structure by the x & y ratios).